# Why fields declaration with var/val not allowed in apply method of companion object

Tags: scala, companion-object

I am using **scala 2.12** and **IntelliJ IDE**. I tried to auto-generate apply method in Scala companion object using readily available template. It generated apply method with fields having **val** because I have created class having fields declared as **val** in primary constructor.

Please refer below code snippet for mode details or [check it here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/7Y8JlGu3SCaXlp5PZIzJmg) :

```
class Name(val firstName : String,val lastName : String)

object Name {
  def apply(val firstName: String,val lastName: String): Name =
    new Name(firstName,lastName)
}
```

I am getting compilation error : **identifier expected but val found**

Why Scala compiler generates error here while using **var** or **val** on fields of apply method ?  What is the important concept behind this restriction ?

Comment: The arguments of a method are always immutable references. So using `val` would have been redundant and using `var` would not make sense, as such this is just invalid syntax. - In any case, that code is equivalent to just `final case class Name(firsName: String, lastName: String)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's the way methods are defined in Scala, there is no need for a `val` or `var` in front of a method parameter. As Luis said, a method parameter is always immutable.

It should just be:

```scala
def apply(firstName: String, lastName: String) = ???
```

I'm a bit surprised but IntelliJ IDEA is fooling you on this one and generating wrong code.

Comment: ah... this is really simple to guess ... due to this IntelliJ idea I got more confused